# Avoid overlapping of a button while expanding navigation drawer in vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Needed some help with figuring out the navigation drawer in vuetify. The codepen for the following is below. So basically there is a toolbar inside the navigation drawer and when i click on the button it should not hide underneath when the navigation drawer expands.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwbNZv

```
<div id="app">
  <v-btn @click="drawer = !drawer">Click Me</v-btn>
  <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="drawer" class="primary">
 <v-toolbar app flat>
  <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer=!drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
   <v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase grey--text">
  <span class="font-weight-light">Todo</span>
   <span> Something</span>
 </v-toolbar-title>
</v-toolbar>
 <v-layout column align-center>
 <v-flex class="mt-3">
 <v-avatar size="150" class="center">
 <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/1.jpg">
 </v-avatar>
<p class="white--text subheading mt-2 text-xs-center">Double A</p>
     </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
 <v-list>
  <v-list-tile v-for="link in links" :key="link.text" router 
 :to="link.route"> 
  <v-list-tile-content>
<v-list-tile-title class="white--text">{{link.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
  </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list-tile>
</v-list>
</v-navigation-drawer>
</div>
```

And my script file in this:-

```
new Vue ({
  el : '#app',
  data () {
return {
  drawer: false,
  links:[
            {text:"Dashboard", route:"/"},
            {text:"My Projects", route:"/projects"},
            {text:"Team", route:"/team"}
        ],
    }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index`. Making the z-index of that button `5` seems to work.

```
<v-btn @click="drawer = !drawer" style="z-index: 5">Click Me</v-btn>
```

If you dont want to use z-index. One other way is to manipulate the toolbar.

```
<v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped" flat>
  <v-btn @click.stop="drawer = !drawer">Click Me</v-btn>
</v-toolbar>
```

One other way is to manually add `margin-left` on the button dependent on drawer state. Drawer's default width is `300px`. Here is sample https://codepen.io/Jubels/pen/rbeBJy

```
 <v-flex class="pl-2">
     <v-btn @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" :style="(drawer) ? 'margin-left: 300px' : 'margin-left: 0'">Click Me</v-btn>
 </v-flex>
```

Comment: The reason i don't want to use z-index is because i want the drawer to push the button to the side. let me see if i can find you an example.

Comment: something like this but i want the toolbar to be inside the drawer and not on the outside https://codepen.io/thiagoaos/pen/KygpxV

Comment: Seems to me it not magically shifting, but the toolbar calculate the padding-left. If you use devtool inspect you can see it.

Comment: Dude you're a godsend. Thank you so much.